# LinkedIn group API auto post via PHP

Tags: linkedin-api

Some one please help me how to post a new discussion in linkedin group using PHP.
I would appreciated if some one comes with an example.

Thanks for all replies.

Cute programmer :)

Comment: FYI, there will be an update to [this project](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) later today that will add all of the Groups API functionality later today.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the Groups API using PHP via the latest version of the Simple-LinkedIn library here:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

The [release notes](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/wiki/ReleaseNotes), covering the additions of the Groups-specific methods. TO answer your question using the library, you'd do something along the lines of the following:

```
$response = $OBJ_linkedin->createPost(<groupid>, <title>, <summary>);
if($response['success'] === TRUE) {
  // success
} else {
  // failure
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you can't.

Long answer, even after 2 years of promising Linked-in still have not produced a suitable API for groups management, despite myself (I'm an LI group manager) and many others who own and/or manage groups on LI repeatedly asking.

now... to look at it from the other point of view:

You don't really need an API to post, after all it is just a html we server, however even with LI you can't do anything without a user login, and that means oauth code to log you in, creation of account, getting a login token and then providing that and a ton more information, as well as the semantics of the discussion.

In short it's not going to be a simple post, even with groups that are open, and for such a simple task it's going to require you a lot of work.

However, if your adamant, then I would start by installing tools like fiddler & wire-shark, then analysing a manual session on LI and observing the process of logging in, creating posts etc ... end to end, so you understand what's sent where.  Once you've done that, it's then just a question of reproducing that in PHP

If your wanting this to write an automated spamming tool by the way, I really wouldn't bother, because the second it gets seen, it will get shut-down and prevented from being used by LI management.

UPDATE:

Looking at the links provided by the OP it appears there is a groups API now, and I have to say it's something that LI remain very quiet about when asked by group owners (Hence the large amount of screen scraping I've done before now)

Moving on, and looking at the sample link you provided:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/12345/posts:(title,summary,creator)?order=recency

I don't know the API yet (Some investigation is required) but, one thing that sticks out is it looks like you

A) Need an account
B) Need to an API key (Presumably so LI can track your usage)
C) Need to have performed some kind of OAuth authentication and logged in before you can use it.

As things stand, I would recommend that you do what I'm about to and read through all the docs. :-)

We've both learned something new here.

Comment: Shawty, thanks for your prompt respond. I recently found some API and this is making me crazy. Am sharing with you http://developer.linkedin.com/apis , What you think here!? What the below link says http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/12345/posts:(title,summary,creator)?order=recency , thanks for your help and I really appreciated

Comment: Hmmmm, now despite asking LI time & time again (We have a need to tie our site in with the group that I help run) we routinely get told there is no Groups API, yet reading the page you link to I can clearly see there is.  Time for me to explore I think. :-)